# How to (efficiently) get the start, end, and count of timeseries data from all SQL tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, performance, processing-efficiency

I have a massive amount of SQL tables (50,000+) each with 100,000+ time series data points. I'm just looking for the most efficient way to get the start, end, and count of each table.

I've tried the following in a loop, but its very slow, I time out when I try to query just 500 tables. Is there any way to improve this?

```
SELECT 
  min(timestamp) as start, 
  max(timestamp) as end,
  count(value) as count,
FROM
  table_NAME
```

Edit: To provide some context. Data is coming from a large number of sensors for engineering equipment. Each sensor has its own stream of data, including collection interval.

The type of SQL database is dependent on the building, there will be a few different types.

As for what the data will be used for, I need to know which trends are current and how old they are. If they are not current, I need to fix them. If there are very few data points, I need to check configuration of data collection.

Comment: (1) What RDBMS are you actually using? (2) Is timestamp indexed in all the (50,000+?!) tables?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Give us some data and expected results

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, `timestamp` (a deprecated synonym for `rowversion`) has *nothing* to do with start and end times.

Comment: Also what are you going to do with these 50,000 independent 3-column resultsets? And if `timestamp` is not indexed, how accurate do max and min need to be (e.g. are histogram values close enough)? Assuming, of course, SQL Server and not MySQL. (As Martin suggests, please only tag the database platform you are actually using.)

Comment: I'll be using multiple types of RDBMS, each with 50k+ tables. I'm not sure if timestamp is indexed in all the tables. Data is collected at different intervals though.

Comment: For SQL Server if the column named `timestamp` is indexed then `SELECT  min(timestamp) as start,  max(timestamp) as end FROM  table_NAME` should be able to just do a seek at both ends of the index. Assuming you want `count(*)` rather than `count(value)` then you can get this from metadata.

Comment: For older MySQL versions, use `ANALYSE PROCEDURE`.

Answer (score 0):

(Note:  The following applies to MySQL.)

**Auto-generate query**

Use `informtation_schema.TABLES` to list all the table *and* generate the `SELECT` statements.  Then copy/paste to run them.

Or write a `Stored Procedure` to do the above, including the execution.  It might be better to have the SP build a giant `UNION ALL` to find all the results as one "table".

**min/max**

As already mentioned, if you don't have an index on `timestamp`, it will have to read all 5 billion rows -- which is a lot slower than fetching just the first and last of values from 50K indexes.

**COUNT**

Use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(value)` -- The latter goes to the extra effort of checking `value` for `NOT NULL`.

The `COUNT(*)` will need to read an entire index.  That is, if you do have `INDEX(timestamp)`, the COUNT will the slow part.  Consider the following:  Don't do the COUNT; instead, do `SHOW TABLE STATUS;`; it will find *estimates* of the number of rows for every table in the current database.  That will be *much* faster.